# Convert BBQ from tank to wall-mount valve

Tags: gas, propane

I have a normal propane BBQ with a 20lb tank and the standard regulator:

[image: BBQ tank and regulator]

I'm moving into a house with large propane tanks for the furnace, fireplace, range, and has a wall-mount valve for the BBQ outside:

[image: wall-mounted propane valve]

**What do I need to hook the BBQ to the valve?**

Is this a quick-disconnect port, and is that non-standard? I can only readily find stuff on natural gas and/or hoses with threaded connections.

Comment: Dude... that's super handy! Someone, somewhere would have to have a "standard" propane screw fitting to quick release adapter. I don't know where you live, but I'd try places like Tractor Supply or Rural King.

Comment: I would check with stores that specialize in propane BBQs.

Comment: Would also get a dust cap for it.  To keep out bugs, dust, dirt.

Comment: https://www.amazon.com/SHINESTAR-Connection-Propane-Blackstone-Portable/dp/B07Q2Q5LPN/ref=sr_1_15?dchild=1&keywords=propane+regulator+long+hose&qid=1635289118&s=lawn-garden&sr=1-15 ... and you may need an adaptor....    Also note it is serious business having a super tank feeding your grill.   But as I have found out by forgetting to turn off a burner 1-2 times it can be very costly too.   Think about it.

Comment: Contact the new house's propane supplier. They probably installed it in the first place, so they likely have the mating parts in stock...